# Live audio streaming between mobile phones

Tags: audio, java-me, bluetooth, audio-streaming

We are trying to implement live audio streaming between two bluetooth enabled mobile phones. Is there any package which supports the live audio streaming in J2ME? Looking forwards for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Audio streaming via Bluetooth requires one device to be the source and the other to be the sink, typically mobile phones implement the source role.
So it is not possible unless you add new the required profile role support on the phone.